# Can't create tables with sequences in a non-default schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, sequence

I'm trying to create a system, where I'm wanna sort the data for years (using schemas), for example now I have a schema named `datos_2016` then I create a sequence named `seq_datos`.

When I try to create the table `datos` and set the sequence for `cdata` it says

> "An error has ocurred: ERROR The relation "seq_data" doesn't exits"

But if I create the schema "public" and then create the sequence there, no error happens (the table is successfully created).

Why can't I create sequences in another schema?

The SQL CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE datos_2016.data
(
   cdata integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_data'), 
   CONSTRAINT fk_cdata PRIMARY KEY (cdata) USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)

TABLESPACE sistema_data;
```

The Sequence Code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE datos_2016.seq_data
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE datos_2016.seq_data
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE datos_2016.seq_data TO public;
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE datos_2016.seq_data TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the sequence name:

```
CREATE TABLE datos_2016.data
(
   cdata integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('datos_2016.seq_data'), 
   ....
);
```

Comment: Great, that was it! I assumed that not having the "public" schema created did not have to specify the schema

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`nextval('datos_2016."seq_data"')`